# Calculating a 95% CI on the mean - is there an error in my calculation?

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, mean

A [problem from Chapter 10, section 8](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/estimation/mean.html) of the Online Stat Book:

[image]

I consulted a table of critical values of Student's t distribution, and it said **1.729** is the critical value for the 95% CI when the degrees of freedom is 19. Thus my calculation had this form:

> Upper Limit = 14.25 + (1.729)*(1.78425) = 17.334968

Was I mistaken, or is there a mistake in the textbook?

Comment: Asking for a upper limit implies there's a lower one.

Comment: @Scortchi - yes, of course there is. But does this fact affect the caclulation in any way?

Comment: The lower limit could be 0 but it is not clear that a two-sided interval would make 0 the lower cutoff.  It is possible that this is for a one-sided interval.  the number you get and the number in the book differ by only the second decimal place.  So other possibilities are round off error or or differences in interpolation from a t table.  Maybe you can clear up thee issues and then focus on a question that could be answered.

Comment: @MichaelChernick - I don't understand.. I probably should read more about all this.

Comment: You take 5% of the probability in the right tail, but if you need a two sided confidence interval then you have to take 2.5% in the left tail and 2.5% in the right tail.  So in stead of looking 0.05 in the table of critical values you might try 0.025 ?

Comment: In R, if you save your vector as `x <- c(1,4,5,5,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,14,17,19,20,23,24,24,24,29)`, then calculate the error `error <- qt(0.975,df=length(x)-1)*sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))`, the upper limit would be `mean(x)+error` or `17.98448`